# Index Match on row and column

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I am having a bit of trouble getting an index match formula to work.

My data table is in sheet3. In column one I have different items (like `Fasso`) and then I have values for each day in the remaining columns. E.g.

```
Date to Use     31/01/17    02/02/17    06/02/17
FASSO               0.00    12.99   0.00
FBLDR               8.68    8.57    0.00
FBSPB               7.78    8.01    0.00
FBSRB               9.18    9.07    0.00
FCGAR               9.52    9.97    0.00
```

On Sheet1 I have a drop down on item e.g. `Fasso`, and I select a date range whic creates a list of dates below. How can I pull through the correct data for that particular item and each of the dates?

Spreadsheet is [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sen40f9v7aik2ca/Book1.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: Your question is not that clear but I'm guessing you should just lock ranges inside your formula like `$A$1:$A$10` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your attachment, I think you want this in Sheet3, cell B14

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$D$3:$L$46,MATCH(Sheet3!$A$4,Sheet1!$A$3:$A$46,0),MATCH($A14,Sheet1!$D$2:$L$2,0))
```

Some of your dates don't exist in your table (in Sheet1) though, so they will show `#N/A`

Comment: Happy to help. I also edited your question to give you an idea of how to best to ask in future -- after all, the better your question is, the more likely you are to get help :)

Comment: Thanks Callum, all the help is appreciated.